# Why is Rails 3.1 rendering a layout for my 401 page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My controller does not specify an explicit layout, so it is using the default application layout. I have a plain html file for my 401 error page. It lives in public.

This action:

```
def index 
    render :file => "public/401.html", :status => :unauthorized, :layout => false
end
```

renders the 401 page within the layout! It should just render the page, right?

Comment: Figured it out. I added the root path and it worked. I think it may be related to the asset pipeline. `render :file => "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/401.html", :status => :unauthorized, :layout => false`

Comment: Matt, please add this as your answer and accept it. This is highly encouraged SO behaviour so others having the same issues can easily recognise that there is a solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. It should work:

```
def index 
    render :file => "public/401.html", :status => :unauthorized, :layout => false 
end
```